# android studio doesn't let me close projects

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

Since I imported a certain android project to android studio, I can't close projects (windows) anymore.
Instead it shows following error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNErrorCode:
>   org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNErrorCode

Something seems to be screwed up with the svn integration it seems.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution which works for me:

Disabled the SVN plugin in Preferences/Plugins/Subversion Integration